# Metamask mint fee too high

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

I have mint function written in solidity:

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(!paused, "the contract is paused"); // false in this case
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(_mintAmount > 0, "need to mint at least 1 NFT");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "max mint amount per session exceeded");
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {            // not the owner
        if(onlyWhitelisted == true) {         //false in this case
            require(isWhitelisted(msg.sender), "user is not whitelisted");
            uint256 ownerMintedCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
            require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= nftPerAddressLimit, "max NFT per address exceeded");
        }

        if(_mintAmount==1&&balancesGoldenTicket[msg.sender]>=1&&freeMint[msg.sender]==0){
            freeMint[msg.sender]+=1;
        }else{
             // this is entered
             require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "insufficient funds");
        }
    }
    
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
        addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
      _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
    }
  }
```

price of nft is 0.15 and when I try to mint 2, price is 0.3 but the gas is outrageous
[image]

Contract address: 0x952997De3c0f9656c4a0F52B2035B3aC7a6DB55b

Comment: The error message says the transaction will revert. It is likely one or several pre-conditions will fail.

Comment: @Ismael but why is price so high

Comment: Because it will fail.

Comment: You are probably not allowed to mint and the tx will fail.metamask show crazy fees when the tx is going to fail